# string comparision between input.name and another string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why I cant compare two strings? example:
radios[i].name contains string "test".

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
console.log(radios[i].name);
    if(radios[i].name == "test") {
       console.log("OK");
    }
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: The relevant HTML would be helpful. What's `i` in the above code?

Comment: `radios[i].name contains string "test"` You mean the `"test"` is a part of the string `radios[i].name` ? In If condition both should be identical

Comment: radios[i].name.localeCompare("test"); try this.

Comment: You can't compare because you have to learn JS first .

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate this node, and then compare.
change "==" to "===".

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

radios.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.name === "test" && console.log("ok");
 })
```